# Many errors when "Add Moles Assembly for mscorlib"

Tags: unit-testing, moles, pex, pex-and-moles

I want to de-tour some method calls into the mscorlib assembly, so I tried to generate a Mole assembly for mscorlib. But it gives me thousands of errors.

I am using Win8+VS2010, VS2012 is installed on my box, too.

What I did is:

Step 0: Create an empty test project in VS2010.

Step 1: Right click the Reference and choose "Add Moles Assembly for mscorlib".

Step 2: Build the solution.

It gives me thousands of errors as below:

[image]

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Net 4.5 and moles don't like each other, see the following work around by Microsoft
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/molesdev11.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the information. It turns out Fakes is the replacement of moles. But I find Fakes **don't like** System.ServiceModel assembly, either. What a world full of conflict...

Comment: Fakes are only available in VS 2012 ulitimate - so it may be work in progress.